# Public site with wildcat certificate for testing

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

Is there a public web site that uses an SSL wildcard certificate (e.g., *.example.com) that I could use for testing to check that a particular client user agent supports wildcard certs?

Comment: You probably meant wildcard, didn't you?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp yup, typo. Fixed.